# How to publish the working source code of a full angular application to npm?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, publish, micro-frontend

Micro-frontend investigation. I created a sample angular application with the cli and instead of bootstrapping the application, I create an entry point like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { R3CompAngGeneratedModule } from './r3-comp-ang-generated.module';

enableProdMode();

export const mount = (htmlElement: HTMLElement) => {
  htmlElement.innerHTML = `<app-root></app-root>`;
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(R3CompAngGeneratedModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I set the entry property of the package.json to point to this ts file, pack it, publish and in another project, I install it and call it like this:

```
import { mount } from 'r3-comp-ang-generated';
const root = document.getElementById("angular-root");
mount(root);
```

Then with webpack I bundle it together (using the second code snippet as the entry point) and run it locally. And to my biggest surprise, I get an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
at syntaxError (util.ts:100)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata(metadata_resolver.ts:959)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (metadata_resolver.ts:839)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (metadata_resolver.ts:683)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (metadata_resolver.ts:453)
at metadata_resolver.ts:589
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (metadata_resolver.ts:572)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (metadata_resolver.ts:453)
at metadata_resolver.ts:551
```

The mounting technique works on the cli generated project. I hit ng serve and I can see the application. (before publishing it)

This exact approach works wonderfully with react (with a generated project). Why can't I do the same with angular? I am pretty sure the CLI project has something magical in the build procedure that I can't see into. Ejecting is not an option, due to angular 6+ hasn't implemented the feature yet.

I'd like to do it this way so that I can use npm as a tool to take care of versioning and dependencies. For example, if I'd import two angular application, one running on ^6.0.0 and another on ^6.2.0, then in the final bundle I would end up having only one instance of ^6.2.0 .

Thank you very much!

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm getting the same error with angular 7.2.15 and systemjs 0.21.6